# Qualcomm Atheros Bigfoot Killer E2200 Ethernet not working in linux

Tags: wireless, networking, atheros

I recently installed Ubuntu -vesrion 12.04 on my system, and it appears it's a common issue that this Ethernet does not work with Ubuntu. I stumbled upon [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2008332) solution. But I don't think the very first packages to install exist anymore.

Is there maybe another solution floating around, maybe a more recent solution? I would really love to move away from the Windows platform. I don't know if this makes a difference, but I am dual booting Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a search on the same problem and found some answers that are not very promising. Nevertheless, I want to share them with you:

1. Unix & Linux SE: [What Linux Distro contains support for Killer E2200 Ethernet chip?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74617/what-linux-distro-contains-support-for-killer-e2200-ethernet-chip)
2. UbuntuForums: [Qualcomm Atheros Bigfoot Killer E2200 Ethernet working in linux](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2008332)

The solution seems pretty complicated for my level of Ubuntu expertise, and not everybody can replicate the solution. But who knows, maybe it will work for you. Good luck and let the others know how it went.